# Uploading a zip file from relative directory fails on Windows using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby. It works well in Mac

Tags: ruby, windows, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

We are currently working on an web application testing using Selenium-Webdriver with Ruby. Originally we only test the OSX platform, until recently we realize that Windows platform should also be tested, (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera). But those following lines code that work well on OSX fails on Windows(7 & 8).

I want to upload a zip file from relative directory on Windows, like "./assets/application/www.zip"

```
@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px';arguments[0].style.height = '1px';arguments[0].style.opacity = 1",upload_a_zip_btn)
upload_a_zip_btn.send_keys (File.expand_path("../../assets/application/www.zip",__FILE__)) # 1
upload_a_zip_btn.send_keys ("assets\/application\/www.zip") # 2
upload_a_zip_btn.send_keys "C:\\www.zip" # 3
```

I tried all the 3 conditions, but only the 3rd works.

The error appeared in Browser said some error like "no attached file"

Does anyone know how to deal with such situation? Thanks

Comment: what happens if you change the / to \ for example : File.expand_path("..\\..\\assets\\application\\www.zip",__FILE__))

Comment: or try using File.join("assets", "application", "www.zip")

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried these two, but didn't work as well, it was with the same error. Or how can I tell where the root of the error ? I don't think it was caused by the Web App.